# ko observable not showing value

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a ko observable variable declared within a view model

```
        selectedResource: {
            func: ko.observable
        },
```

This variable is being accessed within the javascript. This code is working fine and displays the variable values within the brower log

```
loadResourceMethodsAction: function(resource){
            console.log("Load Methods Action");
            this.bindings.selectedResource(resource);
            console.log(this.bindings.selectedResource().displayName());
            console.log(this.bindings.selectedResource().description());
            console.log(this.bindings.selectedResource().relativeUri());
        }
```

However when I try to read the same variable my DUST template. it fails to read it.

```
<p>TODO Methods</p>
<p>Selected Resource:</p>
<p>Display Name:<span data-bind="text: selectedResource.displayName"></span></p>
<p>Description :<span data-bind="text: selectedResource.description"></span></p>
<p>Relative URI:<span data-bind="text: selectedResource.relativeUri"></span></p>
```

I tried attaching () to both selectedResource and displayName but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to call it.

```
func: ko.observable
```

sets func to the actual ko.observable function; it doesn't call the function to actually create a knockout observable property.

Just change it to

```
func: ko.observable()
```

or

```
func: ko.observable(<default value>)
```

---

That said, are you sure you don't want the following?

```
selectedResource: ko.observable()
```

Comment: I finally got it working. Not sure if its the right way or not
    `selectedResource: {
                func: function() {
                    return ko.observable(0);
                }
            },`

Then I access the variable using `selectedResource().displayName`

Comment: @Vinit - I can't see how that could possibly work, though I could certainly be missing something.  Again, I think you want simply `selectedResource: ko.observable(0)`